# Which is the weakest hashing algorithm?

Tags: encryption, hash

After studying about hashing algorithms and encryption formulas, I was interested to find which hashing algorithm was the weakest of all. I'm sure it is some weak and old algorithm, but it would be cool to know because I'm planning to make a cracking program and this would be a great starting point. Thanks in advance!

Comment: map any data to the hash value being the data itself. BAM! bad hash.

Comment: Asking "What is the weakest hash algorithm?" is akin to asking "What is the wrongest possible spelling of the word Fish?". There is no meaningful answer.

Comment: I mean okay. Why do you guys just downvote the question? I'm a beginner and I find it quite acceptable to ask these questions. As a programmer, I know that being an expert I need to help beginners and not just outright criticize them about their curiosity. Just please. @Gilles gave a pretty good answer in a non-attacking way and I thank him for that.

Comment: I would map all input to the letter Q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is not really meaningful because there isn't a linear scale where algorithms can be rated.

Non-cryptographic hashing algorithms are weak in the sense that they don't have the expected properties of cryptographic hashing algorithm. So if you're looking for hashes that are completely broken as cryptographic algorithms, look for non-cryptographic hashes, such as [CRC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check). About the simplest hashing algorithm is [parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_bit), which with a single bit of output can't do miracles.

But algorithms that are designed as cryptographic algorithms are usually not broken in the sense that *all* the expected properties are violated. Rather, there are specific ways in which *some* expected properties are violated. Typically, algorithms that were once considered good cryptographic algorithms remain strong against [preimage attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack) but no longer have [collision resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_resistance). This is the case for [MD4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD4), [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) and [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1).

Comment: So, you mean that secure cryptographic algorithms can't be broken entirely, so you can't access the entire data but some properties are violated? That's what I understood.

Comment: @GauravMall Yes, that's right. For example MD5 was very widely used but these days it shouldn't be used anymore. It's still secure against preimage attacks though. It's only insecure against collision attacks. The reason it shouldn't be used is that there are many protocols which are obviously broken if the hash isn't preimage-resistant, and are also broken if the hash isn't collision-resistant but the attack is a lot more subtle.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for the answer very much.